# Obtener el max valor de una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes, estoy tratando de capturar un valor de mi base de datos mediante un query pero este me da error, el código es el siguiente:

```
    $consultarRepresentante = mysqli_query($conexion, 
    "select max(id_representante) from representantes")  or die 
    ("Problemas en el query".mysqli_error($conexion));
    $registros = mysqli_fetch_array($consultarRepresentante);
    echo $registros;
```

Aqui el error:
[image: Error SQl]

Comment: Cual es el log de error?

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que `$registros` hace referencia a todas las columnas que extraes de una tabla, si quieres hacer referencia a una única columna debes de hacerlo así:

```
echo $registros['id_representante'];
```

Comment: muchas gracias, era eso:

Answer (score 0):

$registros es el arreglo con el resultado del query
Sugiero hagas:

```html
 $consultarRepresentante = mysqli_query($conexion, 
    "select max(id_representante) as max_id from representantes")  or die 
    ("Problemas en el query".mysqli_error($conexion));
$registros = mysqli_fetch_array($consultarRepresentante);
echo $registros['max_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haria de esta manera:

```
SELECT id FROM representantes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Si solo se necesita un campo, usar `max` es mas eficiente. Si fuera necesario devolver mas que solo `id`, allí sí, tu consulta funcionaría mejor.

Comment: @sstan el detalle es que no es solo la Id, es la última Id que se registró, ya que está me sirve de clave foránea para otra tabla o query

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_fetch_array: te indica el formato de respuesta de tu consulta. Existen otros como por ejemplo object, assoc. Más info en este enlace: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php